# how to put data in .csv file with commas(,) in java(netbeans ide)?

Tags: java, excel, csv, netbeans

I want to put my string in (.csv) file.
but if string contains commas, it split and moves to next cell.

String str=resultSet.getString();

Comment: Could you please be a bit more precise about what do you have in `str` and what is the expected behaviour. How do you write the String to the file? What does `moves to the next cell`mean? Could you provide an example for that unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Try Apache Commons CSV http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing a CSV file with comma delimiter and your text happens to have a comma in it as well, you need to wrap your text within *double quotes*:

```
String str = "\"hello, world\"";
```

So, if the string you want to write is `str`:

```
String str = ...;
...
str = "\"" + str + "\"";// do this before put str content in your csv file
```

This should work.

Comment: I have already try this but it split my string and move second part in next cell.

Comment: Do you use a particular library or are you write the file by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Double quote the column value if there's an embedded comma:

Ex:

```
column1_data, column2_data, "column3_data, new_data", column4_data
```

here it will consider `column3_data, new_data` as value in column3